# Задача, поставить перед однозначным числом 0, когда переходит с двузначного

Tags: javascript

Пробовал вот такой вариант но что он не хочет работать, а сам смысл написать таймер с обратным отсчетом. Реализовать хочется на чистом js.

`if (seconds.length <= 1){
          '0' + seconds;
 }`

```
let deadline = '2020-01-28';

    function getTime(endtime){
        let t = Date.parse(endtime) - Date.parse(new Date()),
            seconds = Math.floor((t/1000) % 60),
            minutes = Math.floor((t/1000/60) % 60),
            hours = Math.floor((t/(1000*60*60)));

        return{
            'total': t,
            'hours': hours,
            'minutes': minutes,
            'seconds': seconds
        };    

    }

    function setClock(id, endtime){
        let timer = document.getElementById(id),
            hours = timer.querySelector('.hours'),
            minutes = timer.querySelector('.minutes'),
            seconds = timer.querySelector('.seconds'),
            timeInterval = setInterval(updateClock, 1000);

        function updateClock(){
            let t = getTime(endtime);
            hours.textContent = t.hours;
            minutes.textContent = t.minutes;
            seconds.textContent = t.seconds;

            if (t.total <= 0){
                clearInterval(timeInterval);
            };



        }

    };

    setClock('timer', deadline)

});
```

Comment: [padStart()](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/padStart) не подойдет?

Comment: думаю да, просто в уроке мы такого не проходили, я так понимаю можно пользоваться тем, чем объяснили. А есть еще какие то варианты например через if else? или другие варианты

Answer (score 2):

```js
function customTimestamp() {
    let date = new Date();

    let hh = normalizeValue(date.getHours());
    let mm = normalizeValue(date.getMinutes());
    let ss = normalizeValue(date.getSeconds());

    return `${hh}:${mm}:${ss}`;
}

function normalizeValue(value) {
    return value.toString().length > 1 ? value : `0${value}`;
}

console.log(customTimestamp());
```

Comment: Спасибо большое

Answer (score 1):

самый простой ответ на данный вопрос выглядит так. Добавляем нули с помощью метода slice()

```
 function updateClock(){
            let t = getTime(endtime);
            hours.textContent = ('0' + t.hours).slice(-2);
            minutes.textContent = ('0' + t.minutes).slice(-2);
            seconds.textContent = ('0' + t.seconds).slice(-2);
 }
```